# pgsql2shp - fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgsql2shp

I am at a total loss here.  I receive the error **fe_sendauth: no password supplied** when trying to execute the following pgsql2shp cmd.

> pgsql2shp -f folders/San Bruno/San Bruno.shp -h localhost -u postgres
>   -P xxxxxxxx jcfcqrso "SELECT gid, name, geom FROM places WHERE name = 'San Bruno'"

As indicated above I have supplied the password. The installation appears to be fine as pgsql2shp --help returns the help options.  I have verified the syntax of the cmd also.  What does this error mean?

Edit (adding pg_hba.conf settings):
[image]

Comment: This is likely to be due to pg_hba.conf settings that determine who can log in from where and how. Could you add them to the question.

Comment: Try connecting with `-h 127.0.0.1` rather than `-h localhost`

Comment: does `psql -h localhost -u postgres -P xxxxxxxx jcfcqrso` work?